# Pagination on Custom Post

Tags: php, posts, functions, pagination

I'm trying to figure out how I can display pagination on my wordpress template. Here is my work in progress. So far the page link doesn't show up

```
<div class="eight columns">
    <ul>
    <?php

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $packages = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'articles', 
            'posts_per_page' => 2, 
            'orderby'=> 'menu_order', 
            'paged' => $paged
        ));

        if( $packages->have_posts() ) : while( $packages->have_posts() ) :
           $packages->the_post();
                ?>

        <li class="twelve columns">
            <div class="articles">
                <div class="contents">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <span><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span>
                        <div class="featured-image">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); echo '<img src="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" alt="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '">';  } ?> 
                        </div>

                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </li>

        <?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

          <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are displaying prev/next links. Do you want numbered pagination?

Comment: No, just prev / next links will do. So far it doesn't echo or display anything

Comment: On default is set to 10, but I changed it to display only 2 posts

Comment: Are you sure you have enough posts to display pagination links. By default you need at least 11 posts to display pagination links because by default post per page is set to 10 in WordPress admin.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `WP_Query` to get post from database, you must have to use `next_posts_link()` with `max_num_pages` parameter for our current query.

You can do this as below.

```
<?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;', $packages->max_num_pages) ?>
```

Now your code will become this. I have made above changes in following code.

```
<div class="eight columns">
    <ul>
    <?php

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $packages = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'articles', 
            'posts_per_page' => 2, 
            'orderby'=> 'menu_order', 
            'paged' => $paged
        ));

        if( $packages->have_posts() ) : while( $packages->have_posts() ) :
           $packages->the_post();
                ?>

        <li class="twelve columns">
            <div class="articles">
                <div class="contents">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <span><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span>
                        <div class="featured-image">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); echo '<img src="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" alt="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '">';  } ?> 
                        </div>

                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </li>

        <?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

          <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;', $packages->max_num_pages) ?></div>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @clestcruz Please read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), then revisit all your other posts and accept the answers which solved your issue or at least leave somne form of constructive feedback. Please do not abondan your posts